# Get all NSDates BETWEEN startDate and endDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

My question is the REVERSE of the typical "How do I find out if an NSDate is between startDate and endDate?"

What I want to do is find ALL NSDATES (to the day, not hour or minute) that occur BETWEEN startDate and endDate. Inclusive of those dates would be preferable, although not necessary.

Example:
(I know that these don't represent NSDates, these are just for illustration)

INPUT:
startDate = 6/23/10 20:11:30
endDate = 6/27/10 02:15:00

OUTPUT:
NSArray of: 6/23/10, 6/24/10, 6/25/10, 6/26/10, 6/27/10

I don't mind doing the work. It's just that I don't know where to start in terms of making efficient code, without having to step through the NSDates little by little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add 24 hours to the start date until you go past the end date.

```
for ( nextDate = startDate ; [nextDate compare:endDate] < 0 ; nextDate = [nextDate addTimeInterval:24*60*60] ) {
  // use date
}
```

You could round the first date to noon or midnight before starting the loop if you care about the time of day.

Comment: I used "timeIntervalSinceDate:" instead of "compare:" since timeIntervalSinceDate returns a numeric value, although compare also works. Additionally, "timeIntervalSinceDate" is deprecated, so I used "dateByAddingTimeInterval:"

I thought of doing something like this, but didn't know that I could format for loops like this. Thanks!

Comment: addTimeInterval: is deprecated since iOS 4.

Comment: This doesn't play nice with days that have different number of hours due to daylight savings time.

Answer (score 9):

Use an `NSCalendar` instance to convert your start `NSDate` instance into an `NSDateComponents` instance, add 1 day to the `NSDateComponents` and use the `NSCalendar` to convert that back to an `NSDate` instance. Repeat the last two steps until you reach your end date.

Comment: This also works, but is a bit messier than drawnonward's solution.

Comment: Messier? Nope. More correct? Yes. Drawnonward's solution doesn't take into account any issues that may pop up due to calendar peculiarities, such as daylight saving time etc. Using `NSCalendar` certainly is the Apple recommended way.

Comment: NSCalendar is overkill for sequential days.  Having the start date at noon covers daylight savings.  The fact that days may be a second off 24 hours will not matter until you iterate through 30000 leap seconds and there have only ever been 24.  Leap days are 24 hours.  Using NSCalendar adds unnecessary complication to a simple task.

Comment: Well, in this case you may be able to get away with it, but in general it is a bad habit to forego the NSCalendar route.

Comment: I too wanted to use the NSCalendar approach, but what happens if I am iterating through start date say 2012-01-28 to 2012-02-03? What am I  supposed to set the NSDateComponents's day value after I set it to the max of Jan's 31? Can I set the component's day value to 32? Or should I intelligently set the day to 1 and the month to 2?

Comment: @Raj Yes, you can just keep on counting. No need for any smarts. Otherwise, how would you for example know wether there was a Feb 29 that year. It's the NSCalendar's job to know that.

Comment: @JohanKool, I don't know if it's wrong? But I am doing the same way you told here, I guess!, if you get time, please have a look at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205109/how-to-get-nsdatecomponents-between-two-nsdatecomponents?noredirect=1#comment31932621_21205109

Answer (score 2):

Ever since OS X 10.9 and iOS 8.0 there is the following very clean way to do this. It also deals with end of month jumps.

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let start = NSDate()
let end = // some end date

var next = start
while !cal.isDate(next, inSameDayAsDate: end) {
    next = cal.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: next, options: [])!
    // do something with `next`
}
```

Note that for older OS versions `-isDate:inSameDayAsDate:` can be replaced by some call to e.g. `-components:fromDate:toDate:options:` and `-dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:` can be replaced by `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`.