# How to get NSDateComponents between two NSDateComponents?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I've two `NSDateComponents`, I want all `NSDateComponents` in between those two, I've tried the following,

```
NSDateComponents *first = ...;
NSDateComponents *second = ...;

BOOL boolDone = NO;
while (!boolDone) {
    [array addObject:first];
    first.day+=1;
    NSLog(@"%@",first);

    if([[first date] compare:[second date]] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        boolDone = YES;
    }
}

NSLog(@"All dates : %@",array);
```

After the loop, it just prints the date I've in **first** `NSDateComponent`...!! What's wrong?

Here's a log to understand

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.413 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

```
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 1
Leap month: no
Day: 19
```

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.415 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

```
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 1
Leap month: no
Day: 20
```

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.416 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

```
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 1
Leap month: no
Day: 21
```

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.416 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

```
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 1
Leap month: no
Day: 22
```

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.417 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

```
Calendar Year: 2014
Month: 1
Leap month: no
Day: 23
```

> 2014-01-18 19:47:16.418 testCalendar[4274:a0b]

23-1-2014

23-1-2014

23-1-2014

23-1-2014

23-1-2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always add the same element to the array. The array just hold *pointers* to its
elements, therefore at the end of the loop, it contains n pointers to the same
object `first`. Changing

```
[array addObject:first];
```

to

```
[array addObject:[first copy]];
```

should solve the problem.